# Self hosted Netvibes alternative

Tags: looking-for-a-script, rss

I am looking for a self-hosted alternative to part of the Netvibes functionality. It should act as feed reader, show my mail inbox, a list of bookmarks and maybe the weather forecast.
I wish to move away from Netvibes since I don't care to share my browsing habit, and certainly not my mail password, with another person or company.

I am certainly willing to invest some time in setup, maybe up to writing a plugin for a solution that does not fulfill all my requirements.
Dou you have suggestions on where to look?

Comment: What does "act as a feed reader" mean? That's incredibly vague. Should the feeds(assuming multiple) be aggregated? Each have its own widget?

Comment: I currently display the last items of each feed in a different "widget" on Netvibes (i.e. no more than nine feeds per page, no aggregation). There is surely room for improvement there, though.

Comment: Ah, yes, I only display the headings, of course. But how any software displays the feeds is not a paramount importance for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your question, you want a CMS with integrated webmail. There are many possibilities. I have yet to see a CMS that cannot show feeds, and integrating webmail can range from inserting an iframe to existing webmail to something custom built into the CMS.

Try searching Google for your favorite CMS adding "integrated webmail" to your query, for example [Joomla](http://www.google.nl/search?q=Joomla%20%22integrated%20webmail%22) or [Drupal](http://www.google.nl/search?q=Drupal%20%22integrated%20webmail%22).

You can host these on locally or on a [SynologyDS](http://www.synology.com/) or [Qnap](http://www.qnap.com/) NAS if you want.